# Context based object initialization python

Tags: python, python-3.x, software-design

Thank you for your time. Hope everything is going well  with you during this strange times.

I'm working on a class that represents a list of operations. These operations receive arguments (some optional, some mandatory) and output some values. All arguments are keyword arguments and each operation outputs a dictionary with the results.

Consider that Operation1 takes no arguments and outputs a result called 'arg1'.
Consider that Operation2 takes a mandatory argument called 'arg1' and outputs 'arg2'.

Operations throw errors if a mandatory argument is missing.

```
o = Operation2() # raises error because arg1 is not given
```

In my class List, operation outputs are fed as inputs to the next operation meaning that the following wouldn't raise any errors:

```
l = List([Operation1(), Operation2()])
```

How can i achieve this? Since validation occurs in in the operation init an error will be thrown. I pretend to init the object differently depending if it is inside a List or outside.

I know how to achieve this using class methods and flags but that would change the simple and consistent syntax i displayed above. That's not an option for this project. I have full control about the rest of the implementation of List and all Operations.

Thanks again for taking the time to help me, stay safe!

Comment: ++ only for the very friendly tone and the "strange times"... bloody Corona.

Comment: I may not understand what you are asking, but is what you want not just `Operation2(Operation1())`?

Comment: I pretend the same effect as that but with the syntax displayed in my question. It works better with lots of operations, and for example if Operation2 recieved more arguments that i would want to manually specify it would be stange with that syntax `Operation2(Operation1(), arg3, arg4)` versus `List([Operation1(), Operation2(arg3, arg4)]`

Comment: To summarize i need a way to detect if Operation is being initialized inside a List or not.